# I am getting issues, when compiling my code in codeblocks C++

Tags: codeblocks, catch-unit-test

I am trying to do my assignment for data structures class. The question is 1)  Compile with UNIT_TEST defined and then run with  -d yes to see the time it takes in seconds. Report that time in submission box along with the time you found when testing Selection Sort.  Which is faster?

i am having trouble with understanding, what i am doing wrong. I am getting this error :

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/algAnalysis obj/Debug/main.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Catch::NameAndTags::NameAndTags(Catch::StringRef const&, Catch::StringRef const&)", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
  "Catch::StringMaker<int, void>::convert(int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > Catch::Detail::stringify<int>(int const&) in main.o
  "Catch::makeTestInvoker(void (*)())", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
  "Catch::AssertionHandler::handleExpr(Catch::ITransientExpression const&)", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in main.o
  "Catch::AssertionHandler::handleUnexpectedInflightException()", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in main.o
  "Catch::AssertionHandler::complete()", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in main.o
  "Catch::AssertionHandler::AssertionHandler(Catch::StringRef, Catch::SourceLineInfo const&, Catch::StringRef, Catch::ResultDisposition::Flags)", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in main.o
  "Catch::ITransientExpression::~ITransientExpression()", referenced from:
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatchNotOf<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::MatchExpr(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&, Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatchNotOf<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > const&, Catch::StringRef) in main.o
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatchNotOf<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::~MatchExpr() in main.o
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Vector::EqualsMatcher<int> >::MatchExpr(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&, Catch::Matchers::Vector::EqualsMatcher<int> const&, Catch::StringRef) in main.o
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Vector::EqualsMatcher<int> >::~MatchExpr() in main.o
  "Catch::ReusableStringStream::ReusableStringStream()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > Catch::Detail::rangeToString<std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*> >(std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*>) in main.o
  "Catch::ReusableStringStream::~ReusableStringStream()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > Catch::Detail::rangeToString<std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*> >(std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*>) in main.o
  "Catch::Detail::unprintableString", referenced from:
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatchNotOf<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::streamReconstructedExpression(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in main.o
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Vector::EqualsMatcher<int> >::streamReconstructedExpression(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in main.o
  "Catch::AutoReg::AutoReg(Catch::ITestInvoker*, Catch::SourceLineInfo const&, Catch::StringRef const&, Catch::NameAndTags const&)", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
  "Catch::AutoReg::~AutoReg()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
  "Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherUntypedBase::~MatcherUntypedBase()", referenced from:
      Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherBase<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >::~MatcherBase() in main.o
  "Catch::StringRef::StringRef(char const*)", referenced from:
      ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0() in main.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
     (maybe you meant: __ZN5Catch9StringRefC1EPKcm)
  "Catch::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Catch::StringRef const&)", referenced from:
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatchNotOf<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::streamReconstructedExpression(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in main.o
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Vector::EqualsMatcher<int> >::streamReconstructedExpression(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in main.o
  "Stack::pop(int&)", referenced from:
      SortClass<int>::sort(int*, int, int) in main.o
  "Stack::push(int)", referenced from:
      SortClass<int>::sort(int*, int, int) in main.o
  "Stack::Stack(int)", referenced from:
      SortClass<int>::sort(int*, int, int) in main.o
  "Stack::~Stack()", referenced from:
      SortClass<int>::sort(int*, int, int) in main.o
  "Catch::ReusableStringStream::str() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > Catch::Detail::rangeToString<std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*> >(std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*>, std::__1::__wrap_iter<int const*>) in main.o
  "Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherUntypedBase::toString() const", referenced from:
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatchNotOf<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::streamReconstructedExpression(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in main.o
      Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatchNotOf<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >::describe() const in main.o
      Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Vector::EqualsMatcher<int> >::streamReconstructedExpression(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in main.o
  "typeinfo for Catch::ITransientExpression", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatchNotOf<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > > in main.o
      typeinfo for Catch::MatchExpr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, Catch::Matchers::Vector::EqualsMatcher<int> > in main.o
  "typeinfo for Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherUntypedBase", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherBase<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > in main.o
  "vtable for Catch::ITransientExpression", referenced from:
      Catch::ITransientExpression::ITransientExpression(bool, bool) in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherUntypedBase", referenced from:
      Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherUntypedBase::MatcherUntypedBase(Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherUntypedBase const&) in main.o
      Catch::Matchers::Impl::MatcherUntypedBase::MatcherUntypedBase() in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAI
#define UNIT_TEST
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
#include "catch.hpp"
#endif // UNIT_TEST
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class SortClass
{
private:
    void swap(T &a, T&b);
    int split(T a[], int first, int last);
public:
    void sort(T a[], int first, int last);

};
template <typename T>
int SortClass <T>::split (T arr[], int first, int last)
{
    T x= arr[last];
    int i= (first-1);
    for (int j=first; j <= last-1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j]<= x)
        {
            i++;
            swap (arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap (arr[i+1], arr[last]);
    return (i+1);
}
template <class T>
void SortClass <T>::sort(T a[], int first, int last)
{
    Stack stack;
    stack.push (first);
    stack.push (last);
    while (not stack.isEmpty())
    {
        stack.pop(last);
        stack.pop(first);
        int s= split (a, first, last);
        if (s-1>first )
        {
            stack.push(first);
            stack.push(s-1);
        }
        if (s+1<last)
        {
        stack.push(s+1);
        stack.push(last);
        }
    }
}
template <class T>
void SortClass <T>:: swap(T &a, T &b)
{
    T temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}

#ifndef UNIT_TEST
int main ()
{
    const int N=10;
    int x1[N]={1,3,5,6,4,2,8,9,7};
    for (auto e: x1) std:: cout << e << " ";
    std:: cout << std:: endl;
    SortClass <int> s;     s.sort(x1,0,N-1);
    for (auto e: x1) std:: cout << e << " ";
    std:: cout << std:: endl;
}
#endif

#ifdef UNIT_TEST
using Catch::Matchers::Equals;
TEST_CASE("A fast sort")
{
const int N = 6;
int x1[N] = { 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 };
int x2[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
vector<int> v1(x1, x1 + N);
vector<int> v2(x2, x2 + N);
REQUIRE_THAT(v1, not Equals(v2));
SortClass<int> s;
s.sort(x1, 0, N - 1);
vector<int> v0(x1, x1 + N);
REQUIRE_THAT(v0, Equals(v2));
const int M = 100000;
int x3[M]; int x4[M];
ifstream ifs1("numbers");
for (auto &e : x3)
ifs1 >> e;
ifstream ifs2("sorted");
for (auto &e : x4)
ifs2 >> e;
s.sort(x3, 0, M - 1);
vector<int> v3(x3, x3 + M);
vector<int> v4(x4, x4 + M);
REQUIRE_THAT(v3, Equals(v4));
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

`#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` Must be defined before `#include "catch.hpp"`.

You have `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAI`.